# How to replace a substring converting from and back to byte[]

Tags: java, pdf

In a JSP file, I receive a byte[] representing a PDF file, which I convert to String in order to replace a substring, then back to byte[] to generate the PDF file.
Unfortunately, the former programmers had hardcoded some text in the PDF and now, just to replace those strings, I don't want to recompile and redeploy all, mostly because I don't know JAVA at all.

However, given this code:

```
    byte[] bytes;
byte[] bytess;


String  base    = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResource("/") + "img/";


bytes = o.getPdf(id);

String strings = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(strings);

strings = strings.replace("00198","00135");
bytess = strings.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");


DataOutput output = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

response.setContentLength(bytess.length);


for (int i = 0; i < bytess.length; i++) {

    output.writeByte(bytess[i]);

}
```

The PDF is shown by Chrome, but 00198 is still there. 
Why is this ignoring the replace command?

************** EDIT *********************

If I save the file as TXT I can see this... (can it help me somehow?)

```
%PDF-1.4
```

%âãÏÓ
2 0 obj <>stream
xœ’=kÃ0†wýŠwl‡Ð“?dgTÜ3­$jî¥CIúÿ#Ç¡^*SnÇóðÞúVQµAOò¦XÔËÜy54AÞ•åÒ¨:BÝäÖ§ºûú9Ÿïåão°^992{N¯IØ'ˆ}âxâ©èV„†×»gNØÁ»”\Œ1N#¿ÊÉM[Òÿa·ÙìÛ«¬7"Ý-ÂºG;l’¦[È“³ˆ£
¡ûÃõ0õ2‘Þo{ú%§èmy§ª]A_ÆÌŠ9)bÚP¾Ò•:¸8óJÁ…8+ùë\ W}§
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj<>>>/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>
endobj
1 0 obj<>
endobj
3 0 obj<>
endobj
5 0 obj<>
endobj
6 0 obj<>
endobj
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000457 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000543 00000 n 
0000000300 00000 n 
0000000593 00000 n 
0000000637 00000 n 
trailer
<]/Info 6 0 R/Size 7>>
startxref
768
%%EOF

Thanks

Comment: This isn't about your issue, but you really should not name variables `bytes` and `bytess`.  That is extremely confusing to have 2 variables named almost identically with just 1 letter different that is hard to notice.  Use names that _mean_ something.  For example `inputBytes` and `outputBytes`.

Comment: I think I might need to see the actual PDF file.  Turning a PDF into a string doesn't seem like a good idea (I thought PDF documents were "binary" not text.)  You might be causing problems just by doing that.

Comment: Only very seldom there are PDFs in which you find the text you see when viewing it verbatim in the PDF bytes. Commonly PDF content streams are compressed (have you ever looked for the text from a text file in a ZIP archive?), often content strings are encoded using an arbitrary ad-hoc encoding, and also commonly strings are split up and separated by text position adjustments. Thus, chances are your simple approach won't work at all.

Comment: @markspace *"Turning a PDF into a string doesn't seem like a good idea (I thought PDF documents were "binary" not text.)"* - This is true but by using `ISO-8859-1` you *sometimes* can get away with murder, ehm, with treating binaries as a text string.